# Dom object written in html loaded by Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have introduce a part of the html by Ajax.

my html

```
<div class="article-feed">
    // html is loaded here.
</div>
```

ajax

```
var url = 'getpageplaceinfo/0';
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    url: url, 
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(data){
    $('.article-feed').append(data); 
}
```

It load the html like this here

```
myname        
<input type="checkbox" name="place" value="1">
```

it load the checkbos correctly, but when I tried to get the move of checkbo , it doesn't work

```
$('input[name=place]').on('change', function(){
// not being called
```

Is it correct behaivor??

or How can I handle the dynamically loaded `input`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the event as you defined is bound when the code first runs and will not work on dynamic objects created after that time.

You can alternatively bind to dynamic controls using the following:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name=place]', function() {...
```

This will detect any object (dynamic or static) matching the selector `input[name=place]`.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly for me.and your explanation is very helpful for understanding

Answer (score 0):

You should attach your listener after the HTML has been appended.

```
    var url = 'getpageplaceinfo/0';
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET', 
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(function(data){
        $('.article-feed').append(data); 
        $('input[name=place]').on('change', function(){
            // handle change
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is also nice help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using this?

```
$('input[name=place]').on('click', function(){})
```

Comment: Thank you but it is the same as my post.